# Primefaces how to toggle a dashboard widget/panel visibility using ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, dashboard

I have a dashboard with a considerable number of widgets / panels which are working just fine.

I'm looking for a way to toggle the visibility of a specific one using a commandButton ction listener without having to refresh the page, i.e. via AJAX.

```
<p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardBean.model}">
    <!-- iteration code begins -->
    <p:panel id="#{wdgt.code}" header="#{wdgt.title}">  
        <h:outputText value="One of the dozens of widgets" />  
    </p:panel>
    <!-- iteration code ends -->
    <p:panel id="staticWdgtId" header="Static Widget Initially Invisible" visible="false">
         Some static content
    </p:panel>
</p:dashboard>
```

Then in the backing bean, at some point this action needs to be fired via a commandButton or an actionListener...

```
public void showTheWidget() {
    DashboardColumn dbc = this.model.getColumn(1);      
    dbc.getWidget(2); // does not get a widget object with a visibility attribute :((
                        // so that I could manipulate such as dbc.getWidget(2).setVisible(true);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**STATIC APPROACH**

You can associate the panel with a boolean.

*Panel*

```
<p:panel id="staticWdgtId" header="Static Widget Initially Invisible" 
         visible="#{bean.panelShow}">
     Some static content
</p:panel>
```

*Button*

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.actionListener()}" 
                 value="Button"
                 update=":staticWdgtId" />
```

*Bean*

```
public void actionListener() {
    setShowPanel(true);
}
```

---

**DYNAMIC APPROACH**

Render all the panel with `display: none`

*Dashboard*

```
<p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardBean.model}">    
   <p:panel id="#{wdgt.code}" header="#{wdgt.title}" style="display: none">  
       <h:outputText value="One of the dozens of widgets" />  
   </p:panel>           
</p:dashboard>
```

*remoteCommand*

```
<p:remoteCommand name="panelsToShow" 
                 actionListener="#{bean.panelsToShowAction()}" 
                 oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
```

*bean.panelsToShowAction()* you need [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
public void panelsToShowAction() { 
   List<String> panels = new ArrayList<String>();

   //iterate over the panels you want to show, and put #{wdgt.code} which is the id of the panel
   panels.add("Code1");//id
   panels.add("Code2");//id     

   RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
   requestContext.addCallbackParam("panels", new Gson().toJson(panels));

}
```

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   panelsToShow();
})

function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
   var panels = eval('(' + args.panels + ')');
   for (var i = 0, len = panels.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#'+panels[i]).show();
    }
}
```